# Did Killmonger know the location of the sanctums?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange-2016, black-panther-2018

In the 2018 ***Black Panther*** movie, after Eric Killmonger

> Overthrows and presumably kills T'Challa, he takes the throne and is the new king of Wakanda.

After that, his plan (*heavily simplified*) was to supply vibranium-made arms and ammunition to the militia across the world. At this time W'Kabi tells Killmonger that:

> The forces in **New York**, **London** and **Hong Kong** are ready to go.

So, is this just a mere coincidence that the three places mentioned by W'Kabi were cities where the Sanctum Sanctorums were located? Or was there a hidden meaning later explained by the movie producers/writers.

Comment: I'm unsure if `doctor-strange-2016` is needed here, but I've left it in for now.

Comment: Quick google left it unconfirmed but has led to several fan theories, although Infinity War told us nothing. These are 3 of the main cities in the 3 main non-African continents.

Comment: If I recall correctly, he was using operatives/soldiers/spies/whatever you want to call them put in place by the previous Wakandan leaders. *They* may have known that there was particular importance to those locations, and put resources in place accordingly, but there's nothing to suggest Killmonger was made aware of this information. There may not have even been anybody left alive - and who was supporting him - who knew to be able to tell him.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist that makes sense. However, it was mentioned in the movie that Wakanda had spies across the world in almost every city. So W'Kabi talking about just these three doesn't seem to fit

Comment: @Edlothiad maybe you are right; one each in Asia, Europe and North America. or maybe the writers just forced in an easter-egg by putting in the names of those cities.

Comment: Most likely they were chosen for the same out-of-universe reasons - big, "western", historically important cities distributed across the world.

Comment: @Shreedhar of course easter eggs for the hardcore fans is almost certainly a given, they also seem to line up quite fortuitously.

Answer (score 3):

Killmonger most likely **was not aware** of the sanctums' existence. London, New York and Hong Kong are economical and political hotspots of their given continents, who are easy to access and plant operatives in. Seizing control of these particular cities first to cripple the world economy, amongst other tactics, would be peculiarly useful to his plan. There is **no official statement or comment** indicating another reason, linked to Doctor Strange or not.